# Difficulty converting request.POST value in Django

Tags: django, dictionary, post, request

In my Django application, I have a POST request QueryDict whose values I am trying to change. I understand that QueryDict objects are immutable, so I instantiated a QueryDict item that is mutable. The crux of the problem is that the value is a byte string of comma separated numbers coming in from a AJAX call in the front end of the application, e.g. U"2,4,6,7".

Each key value in a QueryDict is inherently a list of values, [U'2', U'4'] so I need to change the single byte U"2,4,6,7" posted from my front end into a list of byte strings [U'2', U'4', U'6', '7']. The problem however is whenever I try to do a split on the string and assign the request POST key value to that new split string, the key value is a list, in a list. e.g. {'expertise': [[U'2', U'4']]}. I tried a contrived solution by iterating through a split list of the values, and appending them into the key value of the request POST item, but it gives me the error

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'append'
```

In a mutable QueryDict object, if each QueryDict item is a list, and it has no value append, than how is it possible to edit the list item ? Is there a simpler way of accomplishing this ?

View Function Code

```
mentors = Mentor.objects.filter(is_active=True, is_verified=True).order_by('last_name', 'first_name')

ajax_post = dict(request.POST.iteritems())

post = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
post.update(ajax_post)

for key in post:
    postlist = post[key].split(',')

    for item in postlist:
        post[key].append(item)

# First attempt that gives list in a list

# for item in post:
#    post[key] = post[key].split(',')

form = MentorSearchForm(data=post)

if form.is_valid():
    mentors = filter_mentors(form.cleaned_data)
```

Comment: You should explain why you want to modify the querydict at all, rather than writing the form validation so that it accepts what's being posted.

Comment: (And Python lists don't have a method called `push` anyway; perhaps you meant `append`?)

Comment: Yes, I meant append. Sorry I've been going back and forth from python to javascript, and sometimes get these terms interchanged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting caught out by the [`QueryDict.__setitem__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.__setitem__). When you do `querydict['key'] = value`, it sets the key to `[value]`, not `value`.

You can use the [`QueryDict.setlist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.setlist) method to set the given key to the given list.

```
querydict = QueryDict('', mutable=True)

for key in request.POST.iteritems():
    postlist = post[key].split(',')
    querydict.setlist(key, postlist)
```

Since you are going to loop through every key in the post data, I think you can remove the `update()` step from your code.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood the constraints correctly, you should use [builtin array type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html).

```
>>> q =  U"2,4,6,7"
>>> import array
>>> ary = array.array('u', q)
>>> [i for i in ary if i.isdigit()]
[u'2', u'4', u'6', u'7']
```